# FFMPEG command causing audio issues

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am converting multiple mp4 video to ts and then stitching it together.

But this **sometimes** causes audio issues on my videos where the audio sounds like it was recorded with two mics at the same time causing loud sound.

I can only reproduce it sometimes and I am still not sure why it's doing that? Can anyone help?

Here is how I am converting to ts from mp4. I have noticed that the longer the video gets, the audio gets worse and its also off by a couple of seconds.

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=48000 -shortest -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac video1.ts

ffmpeg -i video2.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=48000 -shortest -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac video2.ts

ffmpeg -i video3.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=48000 -shortest -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac video3.ts
```

and then I save these paths to a txt and call my stitching command like this

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc finalvideo.mp4
```

Here is the complete output of the 4 videos

```
C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\videos>ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4
ffmpeg version N-90433-g5b31dd1c6b Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100
  libavcodec     58. 15.100 / 58. 15.100
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
  libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1034 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 879 kb/s, 4.17 fps, 4.17 tbr, 12800 tbn, 8.33 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 165 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3208 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3203 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1954 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1805 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 166 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1746 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1744 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard please check edit. Thanks